# MacBook Pro 15 speaker wattage

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, speakers

I am interested in knowing the technical specifications of the speakers supplied with the 15 inch MacBook Pro (2018). They sound distinctively more loud as compared to any other laptop on the market.

Can anyone present the exact specifications of the speakers, more importantly, the wattage (power capacity)?

The specifications are not listed on Apple's product page. It would be great if any tech enthusiast who has checked the parts of the laptop manually or through any other source answers this question. I understand that the rated power is not a measure of the loudness. However, I am interested in this information out of curiosity and for comparing the speakers with other speakers on the market.

Answer (score 0):

Speakers don't have "wattage." They do have the capacity to accept power up to a certain level, but the [technical specifications of this MacBook](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776) do not include the power-handling capacity of the speakers, nor do the specifications disclose the amount of power produced by the computer's audio output circuit.

In addition, however, how "loud" a given speaker sounds will depend a great deal on how the speaker is mounted, as well as the design and layout of the spaces around the speaker within the laptop body, and where and how the computer is placed vis-a-vis the listener.